# Difference between http and https authentication

Tags: http, authentication, https

In school we got one teacher who always asks question which look easy but they are not easy.

So, can anybody please tell me in a very accurate way whats the difference between http and https authentication?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should do your own assignments

Comment: I already tried to get the correct awnser, but it wasnt that easy

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is HTTP inside a SSL/TLS tunnel.

Like a postcard (HTTP) in an envelop (SSL/TLS).

SSL/TLS has 3 main properties :

- **authentication** of the server : a trusted authority has signed the certificate used by the server
- **confidentiality** : only the client and the server can decrypt the data
- **integrity** : the data cannot be modified during the transport without the receiver notice it.

Note: SSL/TLS can be used with a certificate not signed by a trusted authority (but the client will show a warning about that)

Answer (score 0):

**HTTP** does not scramble the data to be transmitted. That's why there is a higher chance that transmitted information is available to hackers. It operates at TCP/IP level. It uses port 80 by default.

**HTTPS** is a short abbreviation of Hyper Text Transfer Protocol Secure. It is highly advanced and secure version of HTTP. It uses the port no. 443 for Data Communication. It allows the secure transactions by encrypting the entire communication with SSL. It is a combination of SSL/TLS protocol and HTTP. It provides encrypted and secure identification of a network server.

**Limitations of HTTPS**---
HTTPS protocol can't stop stealing confidential information from the pages cached on the browser.
SSL data can be encrypted only during transmission on the network. So it can't clear the text in the browser memory.

Answer (score -2):

Fot HTTP the browser performs basic handshake with the server as per the rules of HTTP protocol. It does not validate the authenticity of the server. However for HTTPS the browser validates the authenticity of the server using the SSL certificate with the client. If the certificate is authentic then ssl keys are exchanged between browser and server and all messages are encrypted thus preventing a man in the middle attack. In http there is no ssl certificate and all data is sent in plain text which is vulnerable to man in the middle attack

Comment: The client verifies the server has a valid certificate for the URL. The client is not validated. Further, unless the client can validate that the certificate is for the desired server (sometimes called pinning the certificate) a MITM attack is possible possible with https..

Comment: When I say browser validates the authenticity of the client the client is the client of the browser, which is the server....if I wanted to say that the browser is getting validated I would have said that, I think you have misunderstood my answer

Comment: Yes, I am confused by your naming scheme which is the reverse of the norm. So the server is the client and the client is in a client farm? Does that make the client the server? It really is best to use conventional naming where the client contacts the server. Consider updating the answer to use expected naming.